# Adding HTML hyperlinks to java resource bundle properties files

Tags: java, jsf, resourcebundle

I'm using Java Resource Bundles to manage messages.

I need to display a message in a JSF page and the message also contains some  HTML markup.
Unfortunately the HTML code is also displayed on screen instead of been rendered as HTML by the browser:

I.E

```
Click me <a href="link....">here</a>
```

My message in properties file:

```
clickme=Click me <a href="link....">here</a>
```

My JSF:

```
<h:outputText value="#{messages['clickme']}" />
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSF/Facelets escapes by default HTML special characters in order to prevent [XSS attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) when redisplaying user-controlled data. You can turn it off on a per-`<h:outputText>` basis by explicitly setting the `escape` attribute to `false`.

```html
<h:outputText value="#{messages['clickme']}" escape="false" />
```

You only need to make absolutely sure that you don't do this for unsanitized user-controlled data, which is *everything* which comes in with a HTTP request such as headers, cookies, parameters, body, etc.